# How to fetch column name which contains 0 value

Tags: mysql

i have a table t1. which has the following value.

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| t1 | s1  | s2  | s3  | s4  | s5  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 1  |  0  |   1 |  0  | 0   | 2   |
|----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 2  |  1  |  0  | 0   | 1   | 2   |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

how to fetch column name. which has the value 0.

Comment: format your question properly...and share what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you are trying to get the column/field name which has all the rows 0, or which has all its values as 0. For example: column s3 in your case.

One possible way to get the column is following: 
You first find the sum of each column. Now if a column has all its values as 0, sum for this column would be zero. Having done that, you use an " if " condition to return only those column whose sum is 0. You could also use "concat_ws" to comma separated those columns, in case you have more than one. So, here is the query. Also, let me draw the table again. Its a bit confusing the way you have drawn.

You table name is t1. It has five columns s1,s2,s3,s4,s5 and a total of two rows. You look to find s3, which has all its values as 0.

```
                        # Table t1 #
```

s1           s2            s3            s4               s5
 0            1             0             0                1
 1            0             0             1                0

**select concat_ws( ',' , if(sum(s1)=0 , 's1' , null) , if(sum(s2)=0 , 's2' , null) , if(sum(s3)=0, 's3' , null) , if(sum(s4)=0, 's4', null),   if(sum(s5)=0, 's5', null) ) as empty_column from t1;**